# Separate Characters and Numbers from a String, vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string like this.
**AB24**

I need to get AB separately and 24 separately. Using Regex will be fine.

I already used,

```
Regex.Match("AB24", "\d+$").Value
```

to get 24 out.

Now I need to get AB out? Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to Seperate Number

```
Regex.Replace("AB24", "(?:[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)", "")
```

You can use regex to Seperate Text

```
Regex.Replace("AB24", "[^\A-Z]", "")
```

Comment: Thanks. I used Regex.Replace("AB24", "\d+$", "") and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Use a capture group `( )` to separate your matches.

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match("AB24", "^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$")

If (m.Success) Then
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(2).Value)
End If
```

Output

```
AB
24
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use  `lastNo = Regex.Match(txtNextLot.Text, "/^[A-z]+$/").Value`